# connect the memcache failed by php in linux

Tags: php, linux, nginx, memcached

I write a php file to operate the memcached, but it connect to memcached failed. I execute the code successfully in windows. But when I deploy the code to Linux. Then I test the code by Chrome, it failed. But if I execute the code by command line,it succeed. I have no idea about it. If you know how to solve it, please tell me. I will thank you too much.
Code:

```
<?php
$opCache = new Memcache();
var_dump($opCache->connect('10.0.8.68', 11211));
$opCache->add('key', 'value', false, 3000);
$opCache->close();
?>
```

windows configuration
Apache

Linux configuration
nginx

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what fails when you try to connect and include the error message you are seeing?

Comment: The Memcache::connect() method just return a bool value 'false'. There isn't any error message.

Comment: Can you try running `telnet 10.0.8.68 11211` from the linux machine and check if you can connect successfully?